# Access mysql field from golang struct with underscore

Tags: mysql, go

I'm working with the https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm library. For some reason I can't access some fields that I expect to be there. Those particular fields have underscores in them. For instance when I try to Access SpeName it doesn't fail but it also does not give me a string

```
type Specialties struct {
    SpeId      int64  
    SpeName    string 
    Conditions sql.NullString
    ParentId   sql.NullInt64 
    Hidden     sql.NullInt64
}


func IsFolderNameASpecialty(folderName string) models.Specialties {
    var sSpecialty models.Specialties
    for _, specialty := range Specialties {
        fmt.Println(strings.ToLower(folderName), specialty.SpeName)
        if strings.ToLower(folderName) == strings.ToLower(specialty.SpeName) {
            sSpecialty = specialty
        }
    }
    return sSpecialty
}
```

For Some reason the println is empty. The mysql field is really  `spe_Name` instead of `SpeName`. What tag do I use to allow me to access the field properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm#existing-schema, you want to use `column:` in the struct type tag.

```
type Specialties struct {
    // ...
    SpeName    string `gorm:"column:spe_Name"`
    // ...
}
```